# Effect of uncertainty in a parameter of a probability model on decisions -- follow-up

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, modeling

I wrote this question which was [previously answered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21976/effect-of-uncertainty-in-a-parameter-of-a-probability-model-on-decisions/22076#22076)

> I am exposing several experimental organisms to a toxin in the food.
>   If the dosage is high enough, they will die. I am examining the number
>   that are dead after a day. For practical reasons, the dosage they get
>   is not directly under my control. I have decided to model the number
>   that are dead after one day as a binomial distribution, Bin(n,p).
>
> In order to figure out what p is for my model, I did an experiment
>   with 300 organisms and counted the number that had died after a day.
>
> In the experiment of interest, I have exposed them to a potential
>   enhancer of the the toxic effects. I would like to know if
>   substantially more of the organisms have died. For a particular result
>   m, I can easily compute the probability of m or greater. If this is
>   less than 1% then I accept that the putative enhancer works otherwise
>   I reject the hypothesis that the putative enhancer is an actual
>   enhancer of the toxic effects.
>
> I am wondering if my analysis of the putative enhancer needs to take
>   into account the uncertainty in the value of p. If so, how would I do
>   it? (I am good with R and able to program if necessary.)
>
> Update: I just want to emphasize that I only care if my enhancer works
>   i.e. more organisms die than I'm expecting. Any answer should leave
>   out cases where fewer than expected organisms die.

I realized that I had left out a critical detail. Imagine there are alleles H and h.  The population in which I compute my death rate are all HH.  However, the population in which I measure my enhancer is one that results when an HH organism is crossed with an hh organism: 25% HH, 50% Hh and 25% hh on average. Unfortunately, I can't examine the genotypes of the live organisms. However,  I am able to examine the genotype of the organisms that die.

So to be clear, I do not know the precise numbers of HH, Hh and hh in the starting population.  However, I do have exact numbers of how many dead organisms are HH, Hh and hh.

The question I wish to address is whether the number of dead hh organisms is larger than I expect.  Is there a way to modify the answer to [the previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21976/effect-of-uncertainty-in-a-parameter-of-a-probability-model-on-decisions/22076#22076) to account for this?

Comment: Do you expect the death rate to vary between hh Hh and HH?

Comment: @probabilityislogic Note: I noticed a mistake in my question and I have changed the text to say "The population in which I compute my death rate are all HH".  Now for your question. For biological reaosns, there are two possible scenarios. The first is hh, Hh and HH all have the same death rate. The second is HH and Hh have the same death rate and hh is larger.